# Making a bootable usb that automatically moves files to windows, from the usb stick

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, liveusb

The goal is to make a usb stick i can boot from. Once it boots, the files I put on the usb stick, when making it, are automatically transfered to the computer in questions windows partition.

I thought of creating a live linux usb which i could boot from, and making that run a program to transfer the files. Though I would like a more elegant solution, not having an operating system that is barely used in the background everytime i boot.

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: If you want to boot to this tool, it must run an operating system, so the simplest solution to that is to use something that already exists.  Once you decide upon the operating system you can decide on the language the tool will be written in.  Until you have decided upon the tool's lanuage, and have attempt to write the tool, we can't really help you.

Comment: The tool will be written in python. It is a simple copy operation, I just not sure where to store the files that are to be coppied, if the program is gonna be running by some system mounted partition. Honestly i know very little about how operating systems function, as you can proabably tell.

Comment: Why don't you just have a excitable python script on the USB storage device that you run from within Windows?  Skip the bootable nature of the drive.  This will allow you to skip trying to figure out where to store the files on the Windows partition from within a bootable Linux environment.

Comment: I know exactly where the files are to be stored - system32. This is also why i cant do it from windows since that, as you probably know, requires system permissions.

Comment: Easily solve by permission elevation to that of an Administrator.

Comment: We dont have easy access to administrator privileges. The idea is to make a bootable usb stick that quickly and automatically moves these files.

Comment: If you don't have administrator permissions that means it's very likely you will be unable to change the boot order.  Sounds like you should go to your Administrator and request assistance with whatever task requires you to put files in a folder that requires elevated permissions

Comment: I have been given the bios password for the computers. It would just be easier to install the files without requesting administration privileges for 200 computers.. I am really just looking for a way to run an executable from a USB stick on boot.